# NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval on completion event

Tags: objective-c

I am using  `NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` to delay function calls, but I need an on completion event too. For some reason I can't find any mention of this in the specs.

What are my options?

Comment: You need to clarify what you are looking for. Perhaps you should post your relevant code and explain what you need different.

Comment: @rmaddy don't be a crazy person. I need an on completion event attached to the timer. What can be more simple than that?

Comment: A timer calls a method each time the timer fires (once if not repeating). So what you are asking make no sense since it already makes a call. What else do you need?

Comment: @rmaddy Just think about it, use your imagination. The timer does its thing 10 times, then after 10 runs I need to run a completion code.

Comment: That's just it. An `NSTimer` doesn't work that way. The only way to stop a repeating timer is for you to explicitly invalidate it. And since your code will be doing that, you can call whatever "completion" code you want at that time. Again, what is the issue? `NSTimer` has no concept of "completion".

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I got your answer correctly. After invoking the selector by

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10f
                                 target:self 
                               selector:@selector(onFire)
                               userInfo:nil 
                                repeats:NO];
```

it is sufficient to simply put the call to a completion method on the bottom of the method which is fired. Does this not fit your request?

```
- (void)onFire {
    // DO THE JOB.
    // ...
    [self onCompletion];
}

- (void)onCompletion {}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be `[self onCompletion];` instead of `onCompletion();`?

Comment: @rmaddy Oops, too much Java today :)

Comment: not good. I need this like an anonymous method in C#, so that I can nest some code.

Comment: @user3077725 Then go for the block syntax, as described by the post of Boreham, below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear as to why the other answers are not to your liking but here is an alternative method.

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(<#delayInSeconds#> * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    <#code to be executed after a specified delay#>
});
```

This should make it easy for your to delay some nested blocks.